# Table 3 types of text aligning

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying the following:
Table, with 2 columns. Second column I want 3 groups of text aligned differently.
I tried something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <image>
    </td>
    <td>
    <table>
       <tr align="top">
            <text at the top>
       </tr>
       <tr align="center">
              <text in the middle>
        </tr>
        <tr align="bottom">
              <text at the bottom>
        </tr>
     </table>
     </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you need to use `CSS` on this one

Comment: The [`align` and `valign` attributes have been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#Attributes) and shouldn't be used. They are obsolete in HTML5. Use the [`vertical-align` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) and [`text-align` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Adding style in to  element never gives me the correct output so apply it to  elemment

CSS sheet

```
.top td
{
  vertical-align:top;
}

.middle td
{
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.bottom
{
 vertical-align:bottom;
}



<table>
   <tr class="top">
        <text at the top>
   </tr>
   <tr class="center">
          <text in the middle>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bottom">
          <text at the bottom>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: It didn't work, but thanks so much for trying to help. I don't know why it's not working. Is it maybe because the css sets the style for the td and we're working with tr?

Answer (score 0):

From the words in the sketch of code, it seems that you want the cell contents *vertically* aligned. The attribute to be used is then [`valign`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#adef-valign), not `align` (which aligns horizontally). For it, the value for centering is `middle`, not `center`.

Moreover, the approach in the markup is unnecessarily complicated. Nested tables are valid, but seldom needed, and mostly they make things more difficult. Here the intended layout is much more easily achieved by using a single table, with two columns, so that the first cell spans all rows. In the following example, I have added borders just to show the structure. Also note that have set `display: block` on the image, since by default, an image sits on text baseline, leaving a few pixels empty space below it, which is probably not desirable here.

```html
<table border>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/170" alt=""
             style="display: block">
    <td valign="top">
        Text at the top.
<tr>
    <td valign="middle">
        Text in the middle.
<tr>
    <td valign="bottom">
        Text at the bottom.
</table>
```

It’s a different issue whether you should use CSS instead of presentational HTML attributes. And yet another issue whether you should use a table for layout only, as you are apparently doing. There is no shortage of “lectures” on such issues, so I have focused on answering what seems to be the question.